# SSIS Package stuck up in Pre-Execute stage

Tags: performance, ssis, temp-tables, delayed-execution

We are having a SSIS Package, which is taking very long time in the `Pre-Execute` stage once in a while.

**Background:**

We have to pull sales transaction information from a humongous database.

What we are doing in our SSIS package is:

1. **Execute SQL Task:** Create global temporary table to hold the transactionIds with unique clustered index
2. **Data Flow Task:** Select query to pull transaction information by joining with the global temporary table created in Step No. 1 and load to target table in another SQL Server.

**What is our issue:**
Step No.2 is stuck up in the `Pre-Execute` stage for long time. When I run `sp_whoisactive` on the source server, there is nothing running in the humongous database.

When I query SSIS catalog, it comes as given below. The last row, `Pre-Execute` is stuck for more than 7 hours. The Package generally completes within an hour.

| message |
| --- |
| Load staging table from HumongousDB:Validation has started. |
| Load staging table from HumongousDB:Information: Validation phase is beginning. |
| Load staging table from HumongousDB:Validation is complete. |
| Load staging table from HumongousDB:Information: Prepare for Execute phase is beginning. |
| Load staging table from HumongousDB:Information: Pre-Execute phase is beginning. |

**What we have already done in our package:**

- DelayValidation to True in the Data Flow Task & connection managers for source, destination
- ValidateExternalMetaData to False in Data Flow Task source & destination

> **Our SSIS Catalog SQL Server version is:**
> Microsoft SQL Server 2016
> (SP2-CU15) (KB4577775) - 13.0.5850.14 (X64)   Sep 17 2020 22:12:45
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on
> Windows Server 2012 Datacenter 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

can you please guide us on what can we do to avoid this issue ?

Comment: SSIS might be struggling to get the metadata from that global temp table, have you tried creating the global temp table as an actual table instead? Its going to give you more work to do because you'll need to `TRUNCATE`, `DROP INDEX`, load data then `CREATE INDEX` maybe package those steps into a `STORED PROCEDURE` and call the proc before doing your dataflow. Using temp tables and SSIS always causes instability in my experience, its always better to use an actual table

Comment: Have you tried not doing the indexed temp table and rather package the logic into a CTE that joins to your main table? Using a CTE might simplify the process and still give you the performance of your indexed mapping temp table

Comment: @Ockert, Thanks for your feedback. This global temporary table, we are subsequently using in a Execute SQL task , by joining with other tables. As you have suggested, let us try with physical table and see if it is improving the performance. Again, thanks for your suggestion. CTE is not possible here, as we need to load data from another server and subsequently use in the query.